# Typescript: Class that implements at least a specific interface

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I have the following question. Let's say i have an Interface like this

```
interface Animal<T>{
   children: Array<T>
}
```

now i want to write a method which will later take in e.g. a bird (a class that implements Animal). At the time writing the method the definition for bird does not exist yet. It could also be it would be given an instance of Shark. But the minimal requirement will be that any object it receives will be an instance of a class that implements Animal.

```
function doSomething(AnAnimal){
   //Do something with animal
}

// Implementation with a class that implements Animal

class Bird<T> implements Animal{
   children: Array<T>;
   color: string;
   chirp(){console.log('peep')}

   constructor(Color:string){
      this.color = Color;
   }
}

let tweety = new Bird('yellow');

doSomething(Tweety)
```

I hope I could make clear what I'm trying to do and you have an idea how i could solve this in TypeScript.

Comment: `function doSomething<T>(animal: Animal<T>)`?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to require a type `T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flow your type arguments throughout your example...

```
interface Animal<T>{
   children: Array<T>
}

function doSomething<T>(arg: Animal<T>){
   //Do something with animal
}

class Bird<T> implements Animal<T>{
   children: Array<T>;
   color: string;
   chirp(){console.log('peep')}

   constructor(Color:string){
      this.color = Color;
   }
}

let tweety = new Bird('yellow');

doSomething(tweety);
```

For example, `Bird<T>` must implement `Animal<T>`. The `doSomething` function must be generic in order to deal with an argument of type `Animal<T>`.

## Non-Generic Version

You might find that you are tying yourself up unnecesarily in type arguments here - so you might want to try the non-generic version.

```
interface Animal {
    children: Array<Animal>;
}

function doSomething(arg: Animal) {
    //Do something with animal
}

class Bird implements Animal {
    children: Array<Bird>;
    biggestEnemy: Animal;
    color: string;
    chirp() { console.log('peep') }

    constructor(Color: string) {
        this.color = Color;
    }
}

let tweety = new Bird('yellow');

doSomething(tweety);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what i was looking for. I noticed another mistake in my code. It's supposed to be

class Bird<T> implements Animal<Bird>

or am i wrong?

Comment: One last question. What e.g. that i have anoter parameter in Bird called "BiggestEnemy" which would be an instance of a class that implements Animal. How could you write that?

Comment: It is `Animal<Bird>` if the children must be limited to `Bird`. I guess if we're talking real life that's true! `Bird` would not need to be generic in that case, it would just be `class Bird implements Animal<Bird>` and the children would be `Array<Bird>`.

Comment: `BiggestEnemy` is tricky unless you know that birds are eaten by cats, so it would be `biggestEnemy: Animal<Cat>` as in, we don't know _which_ cat, but it's definitely a cat.

Comment: Ok this is actually exactly the point where I'm failing now :D

Comment: @relief.melone the non-generic version might work better if you don't know it's definitely a cat.

Comment: Definately seems like it. Seems like you get caught in an endless loop if you are trying to solve this with generics